# When to use and not use @Mock annotation, @MockBean annotation, @InjectMock annotation & @Autowired annotation in a spring webflux reactive project

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, springmockito

Can you please explain when to use below annotations and when not to use those. I am pretty new to testing frameworks and confused with all the answers in the web.

```
@Mock
private Resource resource;
@MockBean
private Resource resource;
@InjectMock
private ProductService productService; 
@AutoWired
Private ProductRepository productRepo;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**@Mock**

Used to make Mockito create a mock object.

**@InjectMock**

When you want Mockito to create an instance of an object and use the mocks annotated with `@Mock` as its dependencies.

**@AutoWired**

Used when you want to autowire a bean from the spring context, works exactly the same as in normal code but can only be used in tests that actually creates an application context, such as tests annotated with `@WebMvcTest` or `@SpringBootTest`.

**@MockBean**

Can be used to add mock objects to the Spring application context. The mock will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context. If no bean of the same type is defined, a new one will be added. Often used together with `@SpringBootTest`

So normally you either:

- Use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` for running tests without a Spring
  context, this is preferred as it's much faster.
- Use `@SpringBootTest` or `@SpringMvcTest` to start a spring context together with `@MockBean` to create mock objects and `@Autowired` to get an instance of class you want to test, the mockbeans will be used for its autowired dependencies. You use this when writing integration tests for code that interact with a database or want to test your REST API controllers.